# How to loop over all the product details in an html file?

Tags: loops, go, range

In this code, I am trying to loop over all the product details in an HTML file using `range` but it is giving me an error

**Error**

```
executing "body" at <.>: range can't iterate over {[product-names...] [product-images...] [product-links...] [product-prices...]}
```

**controllers.go**

```
type ProductStruct struct {
    Names   []string
    Images  []string
    Links   []string
    Prices  []string
}

func ProductsList(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    var pList ProductStruct
    for i := 0; i < len(products.AccessColumns(0)); i++ {
        pList.Names = append(pList.Names, products.AccessColumns(0)[i])
        pList.Images = append(pList.Images, products.AccessColumns(1)[i])
        pList.Links = append(pList.Links, products.AccessColumns(2)[i])
        pList.Prices = append(pList.Prices, products.AccessColumns(3)[i])
    }
    return ProductsListTmpl.Execute(w, pList)
}
```

**product-list.html**

```
{{range $i := .}}
<tr>
    <td class="image" data-title="No"><img src="../../static/images/{{ (index .Images $i) }}.jpg" alt="#"></td>
    <td class="product-des" data-title="Description">
        <p class="product-name"><a href="{{ (index .Links $i) }}">{{ (index .Names $i) }}</a></p>
        <p class="product-des">Maboriosam in a tonto nesciung eget  distingy magndapibus.</p>
    </td>
    <td class="price" data-title="Price"><span>${{ (index .Prices $i) }}.00 </span></td>
</tr>
{{end}}
```

Comment: Is there anyone to answer my question?

Comment: Anyone to answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error accrues because you trying to iterate `{{range $i := .}}` over not related `Names   []string, Images  []string, Links   []string, Prices  []string`. They can have even not equal len.

Try to refactor your solution, to have something like this(It's just a draft):

**controllers.go**

```golang
type ProductStruct struct {
    Names  string
    Images string
    Links  string
    Prices string
}

func ProductsList(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    var pList []ProductStruct
    for i := 0; i < len(products.AccessColumns(0)); i++ {
        pList = append(pList, ProductStruct{products.AccessColumns(0)[i],
            products.AccessColumns(1)[i],
            products.AccessColumns(2)[i],
            products.AccessColumns(3)[i],
        })
    }
    return ProductsListTmpl.Execute(w, pList)
}
```

**product-list.html**

```golang
{{range .}}
<tr>
    <td class="image" data-title="No"><img src="../../static/images/{{ (.Images}}.jpg" alt="#"></td>
    <td class="product-des" data-title="Description">
        <p class="product-name"><a href=".Links}}">{{.Names}}</a></p>
        <p class="product-des">Maboriosam in a tonto nesciung eget  distingy magndapibus.</p>
    </td>
    <td class="price" data-title="Price"><span>${{ .Prices}}.00 </span></td>
</tr>
{{end}}
```